# Controller function not getting recognized in js file

Tags: angularjs

I have a Controller defined in my js file as below. It all works perfect until i change the placement of the "Test2Controller" controller in my javascript file. When i place the Test2Controller below the SampleController function / function declaration it gives me the below error :

Error in Chrome Dev tools :

> Uncaught TypeError: Property 'controller' of object # is not a
>   function mycontroller1.js:26 Error: Argument 'Test2Controller' is not
>   a function, got undefined
>       at assertArg (file:///D:/Dev/olite/workspace/olite/olite/WebContent/AngularJSDemos/mylearnings/angular.js:1039:11)
>       at assertArgFn (file:///D:/Dev/olite/workspace/olite/olite/WebContent/AngularJSDemos/mylearnings/angular.js:1049:3)
>       at file:///D:/Dev/olite/workspace/olite/olite/WebContent/AngularJSDemos/mylearnings/angular.js:4802:9
>       at file:///D:/Dev/olite/workspace/olite/olite/WebContent/AngularJSDemos/mylearnings/angular.js:4384:17
>       at forEach (file:///D:/Dev/olite/workspace/olite/olite/WebContent/AngularJSDemos/mylearnings/angular.js:137:20)
>       at nodeLinkFn (file:///D:/Dev/olite/workspace/olite/olite/WebContent/AngularJSDemos/mylearnings/angular.js:4369:11)
>       at compositeLinkFn (file:///D:/Dev/olite/workspace/olite/olite/WebContent/AngularJSDemos/mylearnings/angular.js:4015:15)
>       at compositeLinkFn (file:///D:/Dev/olite/workspace/olite/olite/WebContent/AngularJSDemos/mylearnings/angular.js:4018:13)
>       at compositeLinkFn (file:///D:/Dev/olite/workspace/olite/olite/WebContent/AngularJSDemos/mylearnings/angular.js:4018:13)
>       at publicLinkFn (file:///D:/Dev/olite/workspace/olite/olite/WebContent/AngularJSDemos/mylearnings/angular.js:3920:30)
>   ...

Working ::

```
var myModule = angular.module ('mymodule',[]) ;

myModule.controller('TestController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Message from TestController';
});

myModule.controller('Test2Controller',function ($scope){
    $scope.message = "Message from Test2Controller" ; 
}) ;

myModule.controller = 'SampleController' ;

function SampleController( $scope ) {
    $scope.customers = [
                        {name:'AAA',city:'Plano'},
                        {name:'BBB',city:'Plano'},
                        {name:'CCC',city:'Bangalore'},
                        {name:'DDD',city:'SanJose'},
                        {name:'EEE',city:'SanFO'},
                        {name:'FFF',city:'SanJose'}
                        ] ;

    $scope.addCustomer = addCust ;

    function addCust( ) {
        $scope.customers.push ( {name:$scope.customerName , city:$scope.customerCity} ) ;
    } ;
}
```

Not working ::

```
var myModule = angular.module ('mymodule',[]) ;

myModule.controller('TestController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Message from TestController';
});

myModule.controller = 'SampleController' ;

myModule.controller('Test2Controller',function ($scope){
    $scope.message = "Message from Test2Controller" ; 
}) ;

function SampleController( $scope ) {
    $scope.customers = [
                        {name:'AAA',city:'Plano'},
                        {name:'BBB',city:'Plano'},
                        {name:'CCC',city:'Bangalore'},
                        {name:'DDD',city:'SanJose'},
                        {name:'EEE',city:'SanFO'},
                        {name:'FFF',city:'SanJose'}
                        ] ;

    $scope.addCustomer = addCust ;

    function addCust( ) {
        $scope.customers.push ( {name:$scope.customerName , city:$scope.customerCity} ) ;
    } ;
}
```

I am currently learning angular js and kinda struck here. What could be the issue here ??

Comment: why dont u use the same controller syntax for SampleController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`controller` is an attribute, or type function, of `myModule`. That's why you can use

```
myModule.controller(...);
```

But in your code, you replace this attribute by a value of type string:

```
myModule.controller = 'SampleController' ;
```

So obviously, you can't call the function `myModule.controller()` after, since `myModule.controller` is not a function anymore.

Remove the line `myModule.controller = 'SampleController';`: it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Hi JB Nizet, As mentioned in the question "SampleController" does not have any issue. The issue is only with the "Test2Controller". First code snippet where "Test2Controller" is placed before "myModule.controller = 'SampleController' ;" works perfectly without any issues. When this moved after "myModule.controller = 'SampleController' ;" , this code breaks. any suggestions ???

Comment: Suggestion: re-read my answer. You're replacing the function controller() in myModule by a String. Obviously, you can't call myModule.controller() anymore after this replacement, because calling a String doesn't make any sense.